# Subclass UITableViewCell with content view loaded from nib

Tags: uitableview

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell and I have the layout of the contentView in an nib. How can I load the view in the nib as the contentView in the subclass?
What method do I load the nib in?
drawRect?

Comment: Can't you make the subclass of UITableViewCell manage all of it's own content? And why do they set self.tvcell to nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Table View Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) from apple.

Look at Listing 5-5  Loading a cell from a nib file and assigning it content.
It does exactly what you ask for.

regards
Yoeri

Comment: The answer is not good enough. It explains how to create a subclass of tablecell however it doesn't explain how to load the tableviewcell from a nib. The subclass draw the cells using codes.

Comment: I mean the sample draw the class using codes. I want to subclass and then draw the cell using nib.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Loading from the nib and have the nib's content in contentView?